# PhalconPHP - Moving the controller-related view folders

Tags: phalcon, volt

I'm developing an application using the PhalconPHP framework, as my application grows larger and larger my views folder is becoming rather messy.

Currently my `views` folder looks like this:

```
views_layouts
    |_index_..
    |_blog_..
    |_news_..
    |_etc_..
```

Is there any way to move my controller related folder to a seperate folder named `pages` so my directory structure looks like this?

```
views_layouts_index.volt
    |       |_blog.volt
    |       |_news.volt
    |       |_etc.volt
    |
    |_pages_index_..
          |_blog_..
          |_news_..
          |_etc_..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this myself by editing the `ControllerBase` class.

```
// Change the default views directory to /app/views/pages/
$moduleName = $this->dispatcher->getControllerName();     // Eg: blog
$actionName = $this->dispatcher->getActionName();         // Eg: index
$this->view->pick("pages/$moduleName/$actionName");       // Result: "pages/blog/index"
```

You can even call `pick()` multiple times to override any view in your controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just change your folder structure into something like this.

```
layouts
 |   controller_name.volt
 |   other_controller.volt
controller_name
 |   action_name.volt
 |   other_action.volt
other_controller
 |  action_name.volt
 |  other_action.volt
```

In the files in the layout folder you can put something like this

```
{% extends "templates/base.volt" %}
{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}{% block content %}
{{ content () }}{% endblock %}
```

And in the templates/base.volt file you can put something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
      <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

</head>

<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

**All this should be in the views folder**